# Why path on Windows is not recognized? error: the path "./m.yml" does not exist

Tags: windows, kubernetes

I must install some kubectl things on Windows
Tried both

```
kubectl apply -f ./m.yml

error: the path "./m.yml" does not exist
```

and

kubectl apply -f m.yml
Got the same.
Dir command shows

```
03/11/2023  16:44    <DIR>          .
03/11/2023  16:44    <DIR>          ..
16/10/2023  09:35    <DIR>          DESKTOP
09/10/2023  08:44    <DIR>          FAVORITES
17/10/2023  14:02       (1 873 815) jconnect-16.0.25.jar
10/11/2023  14:08               359 m.yaml
10/11/2023  14:09               290 rb.yaml
```

How should I kubectl apply?

Comment: `m.yml` vs `m.yaml`.

Comment: You have an error in your syntax. Correct your syntax and edit and update your question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Computers are very good at finding things. When a computer tells you it cannot find something, then in 99.9% of cases, the reason it cannot find the thing is that the thing you are telling it to find is not there. The other 0.1% of cases, you are telling it to look in the wrong place.

In this case, you are telling the computer to find a file named `m.yml` in the current working directory. And, as the output of your `DIR` command shows, there is indeed no file with that name in the current working directory, so the computer is correct: there is no file named `m.yml` in the current working directory.

There is, however, a file named `m.yaml`, so if I were you, I would try that file instead, but only *after* verifying that is indeed the file you are looking for. Just because it has a similar name does not mean it does a similar thing.

You should read the file and verify that it does what you think it does.

Comment: In other words: "your computer will try to do what you tell it to do, not necessarily what you want it to do".